# How to quickly map a combination of elements to another vector

Tags: algorithm, mapping

Suppose I have two set of elements, X and Y. Both sets contain tens of thousands (or more) unique elements. Any combination of elements in X, like (X1, X4, X6, X100, ...), may be mapped to zero, one or multiple elements in Y.

How should I store the data in a SQL database, or algorithmically identify if Y contains elements that correspond to a given set of X elements, and what elements?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem you're facing is that one of the sets you're mapping is a power set (2<sup>X</sup>), which has 2<sup>|X|</sup> elements. If 2<sup>X</sup> is densely used (for instance, if each element in Y corresponds to an arbitrarily large and irregular number of subsets of X), then you will have |Y|*2<sup>|X|</sup> edges in your mapping, which is computationally infeasible to represent in any way.

Two examples of soluble cases:

1. If each y in Y only corresponds to one subset of X, you can represent the relationship in a table with single elements of Y and single elements of X, indexed on both X and Y. The maximum size of this table will be O(|Y|*|X|). The queries would be a series of joins of the table on itself (matching ys) where the x is each of the elements in the subset.
2. If, for every x in X and y in Y, y either maps to any subset containing x or no subsets containing x, then this can be represented by the same table, but the queries would be much easier.